# ASM - What is "%" used for?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

What is the use of "%" in assembly? For example, sometimes an instruction is written as:

```
movl %eax, %ebx
```

and other times it's written as:

```
movl eax, ebx
```

(without the percent symbol) what is the difference?

Comment: Note that `movl eax, ebx` isn't valid in any normal syntax for x86.  Intel-syntax doesn't use size suffixes on the mnemonic.  Probably you meant `mov eax, ebx`.  (Technically could be valid for GAS with `.att_syntax noprefix`, but don't do that, mutant hybrids of AT&T and Intel syntax are confusing for everyone.  Even GAS rejects it as an invalid instruction mnemonic in `.intel_syntax noprefix` mode.)

Answer (score 8):

For all assemblers, there's a problem when you need to refer to a symbol that happens to have the same name as a register. For example, if you've got some C code that has the function "int eax()" in it and you link it with some assembly code that does "mov ebx,eax", then the assembler needs to know if "eax" is the register or if it's the function.

To get around that different assemblers do different things. Some (e.g. NASM) would assume "eax" is the register and would require some sort of prefix for ambiguous symbols (e.g. "$eax" to refer to the symbol rather than the register). Others (e.g. GAS) do the opposite and add a prefix to the register name; sometimes even if there's no ambiguity at all (e.g. "%eax" to refer to the register and "eax" to refer to the symbol).

Answer (score 5):

There are different flavors of [X86 assembly syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax). The one with % is called AT&T. The other is called Intel. Different assemblers use different syntaxes. Some (gas) work with both.